# Why does the "Dissolve" tool in QGIS create an empty layer?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I have a shapefile containing cadastral data.
I would like to dissolve the polygons using my field "OwnerName". My goal is to get one polygon per landlord's name.

When I use the "Dissolve" tool, QGIS creates an empty output layer (but with the right column titles, see the screenshot attached).

First I thought that maybe I could not dissolve some polygons using a field containing some text (my "OwnerName" field), so I created a field containing a decimal number ID for each owner name. I tried to dissolve the polygons again. Same result : an empty layer.
The reason may be the size of the attribute table. I have 65,500 polygons.

Any idea?

Thanks
[image]
(QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa - Windows 7)

Comment: can you display the results i.e screenshoot of the dissolved output?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the empty attribute table of the dissolved output. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try "dissolve all" options, regardless of the attribute value?

Comment: When I "dissolve all" the tool stops around 60% of completion. I tried a few times with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the size of the shapefile.
I ran the Dissolve tool over the week-end and it worked. It took 40 hours to complete the process. The first 1% shows up after 45 mins.
I was not patient enough and though it was not working while actually I should have waited longer.
Thanks

Comment: Consider using postgis or sqlite for speeding up things. Look for instance for `st_unaryunion`